# Command line that outputs the employees from oldest to youngest of this text file?

Tags: command-line

```
2233|charles harris  |g.m.     |sales     |12/12/52|90000   
9876|bill johnson    |director |production|03/12/50|130000  
5678|robert dylan    |d.g.m.   |marketing |04/19/43|85000  
2365|john woodcock   |director |personnel |05/11/47|120000  
5423|barry wood      |chairman |admin     |08/30/56|160000  
1006|gordon lightfoot|director |sales     |09/03/38|140000  
6213|michael lennon  |g.m.     |accounts  |06/05/62|105000  
1265|p.j. woodhouse  |manager  |sales     |09/12/63|90000  
4290|neil o'bryan    |executive|production|09/07/50|65000  
2476|jackie wodehouse|manager  |sales     |05/01/59|110000  
6521|derryk o'brien  |director |marketing |09/26/45|125000  
3212|bill wilcocks   |d.g.m.   |accounts  |12/12/55|85000  
3564|ronie trueman   |executive|personnel |07/06/47|75000  
2345|james wilcox    |g.m.     |marketing |03/12/45|110000  
0110|julie truman    |g.m.     |marketing |12/31/40|95000
```

forgive me for my poor formatting, this is what the text file contains my question is how to sort all of key field 5 that being the dates, for example |12/31/40| MM/DD/YY and the rest of the dates from oldest to youngest from the command line? the delimiter is this |

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that works on Unix Bourne shells or Windows?

Comment: @pete unix shell im working with red hat enterprise 6

Comment: I don't think the `sort` command supports sorting based on dates, sorting this file on column 5 would be `sort -t "|" -k 5,5 file.psv`

Comment: IANAE, but I think `sort` may be able to do this.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html  In particular, the `--key` option and the `KEYDEF` for it.  The fact that it takes a comma separated list of sequences means you may be able to sort by `YY MM DD` which is what you want.  Although every COBOL programmer that was employed between 1995 and 12/31/1999 will be cringing at you data. ;)

Comment: @dgnuff I like the idea, unfortunately, at least on MacOS `sort` seems to take no more than 2 `KEYDEF`s: `sort -t "|" -k 5.7n,5.8n file.psv` to sort by year, but could get no further than that..

Comment: @pete That's a pity.  I was hoping to use a 2 character key holding the year, followed by a 5 character key holding MM/DD.  Oh well.  Failing that, you're looking at awk usage as in mnesarco's answer.  As you are doubtless aware, it's well worth becoming familiar with awk, sed and the other "lightweight" text processing tools, they can often do what's needed without needing to resort to something like a perl or python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an option:

```
cat file.txt \
  | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}{ split($5,date,/\//); $5 = date[3] "/" date[2] "/" date[1]; print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" $6 }' \
  | sort -k5,5 -t"|" \
  | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}{ split($5,date,/\//); $5 = date[3] "/" date[2] "/" date[1]; print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" $6}'
```

Explanation:

1. cat: Cat the file
2. awk: Fix date format to be YY/MM/DD
3. sort: Sort by fixed date column
4. awk: Restore column date format

Comment: I know I should have stated this earlier, I totally forgot, but would this answer work for future employees if they were added to this list?

Comment: @Samzun of course it works with any file with the given format.